# Pass type and instantiate new class

Tags: typescript

I have a function which is responsible for all of the API requests within my application. Everything that I interact with, goes through here.

I want to be able to specify a return type, however this return type is of a class and for it to be recognised and be able to use the methods, I need to instantiate the class, which I was hoping to do dynamically.

```
const sendRequest = async <T>(uri: string, options: any): Promise<T> => {
  // ... do request logic here.

  const data = await response.json();

  return new T(data);
}
```

Now, as expected this didn't work, but I was wondering is there a workaround or anything I can do so that it returns a class instant when passing in the data?

Comment: Without any further constraints, there's no guarantee that type `T` has a constructor which takes whatever the type of `data` is.

Comment: Note that `T` isn't actually a value, just a type, so cannot be used in that expression. You'd need e.g. `klass: new(data: any) => T` as a parameter, then `return new klass(data)` would fill the return type requirement.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do you mean? apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a parameter whose type is a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that returns `T`. Then in the body you can use it to create an instance of the "class".

```
const sendRequest = async <T>(uri: string, options: any, into: new (data: any) => T): Promise<T> => {
  // ... do request logic here.

  const data = await response.json();

  return new into(data);
};
```

This even works when passing `String` or `Number`, but be careful! They would return the types `String` and `Number`, not `string` and `number`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9n28m)